# What is the use of extra and extraoptions in Redux-Toolkit Query? How could we populate them when using the query & queryFn?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am just curious to know the way to populate `extra` and `extraOptions`, and from where the arguments must be passed in order so that they can get populated and can be used then in creating some condition based scenario. Well `queryFn` itself is used for creating custom query function in the Redux-Toolkit (RTK) query (RTKQ).

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const shiprocketApiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, extra, type, endpoint }) => {
      const token =
        "...someToken";
      token && headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      console.log(
        "the extra value of the ====> ",
        extra,
        getState(),
        type,
        endpoint,
        headers
      );
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (user) => {
        return {
          url: `/users/${user.queryArg}`,
          headers: {
            "X-Scope": "1234567890",
          },
        };
      },
    }),
    createOrderShiprocket: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        console.log(
          "printin all the agrs of the qrfn to see what exactly it is ===> ",
          args,
          api,
          "extraoptions==>",
          extraOptions,
          "base==>",
          baseQuery
        );
        
        const response = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        console.log("the response ==>", response);
        return { error: { message: "error occured" } };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation, useUpdateUserMutation } =
  shiprocketApiSlice;
```

I have used the hooks in this file

```js
"use client";

import React from "react";
import {
  useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation,
  useUpdateUserMutation,
} from "@/store/features/shiprocket/shiprocketApiSlice";

const TestFolderPage = () => {
  const [createOrderShiprocket, { data: TheOrderList }] =
    useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation();

  const [updateUser, { data: updatedData }] = useUpdateUserMutation();
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("the click");
    updateUser({ queryArg: 12344 });
    createOrderShiprocket({ userId: 123 });
  };
  return <div onClick={handleClick}>TestFolderPage</div>;
};

export default TestFolderPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the use of `extra` and `extraOptions` in Redux-Toolkit (RTK) query (RTKQ)?

### `extra`

Provided as `thunk.extraArgument` to the configureStore getDefaultMiddleware option.

[BaseQueryApi](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#basequery-function-signature)

```
export interface BaseQueryApi {
  signal: AbortSignal
  abort: (reason?: string) => void
  dispatch: ThunkDispatch<any, any, any>
  getState: () => unknown
  extra: unknown             // <-- specified thunk.extraArgument
  endpoint: string
  type: 'query' | 'mutation'
  forced?: boolean
}
```

`extra` is the extra argument used with Redux-Toolkit's Thunk middleware when configuring the Redux store. See [Customizing the included Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware#customizing-the-included-middleware) for details. The basic example is a follows:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      thunk: {
        extraArgument: /* whatever value you need here */,
      },
    }),
});
```

This `extraArgument` is exposed out in the `thunkApi` of `createAsyncThunk` actions, and apparently as part of the Redux-Toolkit Query's `prepareHeaders` function signature.

```
type prepareHeaders = (
  headers: Headers,
  api: {
    getState: () => unknown
    extra: unknown              // <-- the extra arg from store
    endpoint: string
    type: 'query' | 'mutation'
    forced: boolean | undefined
  }
) => Headers | void
```

### `extraOptions`

See [`extraOptions`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#extraoptions) in the docs:

Quite simply, `extraOptions` is an optional object that is passed as the third argument to the supplied `baseQuery` function, e.g. the base query function returned by `fetchBaseQuery` in your code example. See [`fetchBaseQuery` signature](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#signature).

```
type FetchBaseQuery = (
  args: FetchBaseQueryArgs
) => (
  args: string | FetchArgs,
  api: BaseQueryApi,
  extraOptions: ExtraOptions // <-- third arg, the extra options
) => FetchBaseQueryResult
```

> How could be populate them when using the `query` & `queryFn`?

I've already covered above where and how to specify/add the `extra` value when configuring the store. The `extraOptions` can specified per endpoint.

Example:

```js
updateUser: builder.mutation({
  query: (user) => ({
    url: `/users/${user.queryArg}`,
    headers: {
      'X-Scope': '1234567890',
    },
  }),
  extraOptions: {
    // any custom extra options/properties you want to pass to the base query
  },
}),
createOrderShiprocket: builder.mutation({
  queryFn: async (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {     // <-- accessed here
    ...
    
    const response = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions); // <-- passed through

    ...
  },
  extraOptions: {
    // any custom extra options/properties you want to pass to the base query
  },
}),
```

This alone isn't particularly useful until you have the need to customize your base query function. See [Customizing Queries](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries).

For example, a fairly trivial customization is to add [automatic retries](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-retries) for failed queries.

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery, retry } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseQuery = retry(
  fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, extra, type, endpoint }) => {
      const token = "...someToken";

      token && headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
      
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  {
    maxRetries: 5,
  },
);
```

```js
const shiprocketApiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery, // <-- 5 retries by default
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: `/users/${user.queryArg}`,
        headers: {
          'X-Scope': '1234567890',
        },
      }),
    }),
    createOrderShiprocket: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        ...

        const response = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

        ...
      },
      extraOptions: {
        maxRetries: 8 // <-- override default 5
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

It's really up to you and your app's specific use cases and needs what `extra` and `extraOptions` are relevant and/or helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Modifying `fetchBaseQuery` to Use `extra`:**

Currently, the `extra` parameter in `prepareHeaders` isn't being utilized because it's not set anywhere. If you want to use this, you need to provide a value for `extra` when calling `fetchBaseQuery`. However, typically `extra` is used for more advanced scenarios, like when you have a middleware setting it.

**Passing and Using `extraOptions` in `queryFn`:**

To demonstrate how to pass and use `extraOptions`, I'll modify the `createOrderShiprocket` mutation's usage in your component.

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const shiprocketApiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'https://apiv2.shiprocket.in/v1/external',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState, extra, type, endpoint }) => {
      const token = '...someToken';
      token && headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
      console.log('the extra value of the ====> ', extra, getState(), type, endpoint, headers);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    updateUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (user) => ({
        url: `/users/${user.queryArg}`,
        headers: {
          'X-Scope': '1234567890',
        },
      }),
    }),

    createOrderShiprocket: builder.mutation({
      queryFn: async (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        console.log(
          'printin all the agrs of the qrfn to see what exactly it is ===> ',
          args,
          api,
          'extraoptions==>',
          extraOptions,
          'base==>',
          baseQuery
        );

        // Use extraOptions here for conditional logic
        if (extraOptions.someCondition) {
          // Custom handling based on extraOptions
        }

        const response = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        console.log('the response ==>', response);
        return { error: { message: 'error occured' } };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation, useUpdateUserMutation } = shiprocketApiSlice;
```

And then:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation,
  useUpdateUserMutation,
} from '@/store/features/shiprocket/shiprocketApiSlice';

const TestFolderPage = () => {
  const [createOrderShiprocket, { data: TheOrderList }] = useCreateOrderShiprocketMutation();
  const [updateUser, { data: updatedData }] = useUpdateUserMutation();

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('the click');
    updateUser({ queryArg: 12344 });
    createOrderShiprocket({ userId: 123, extraOption: 'someValue' }); // Passing extraOption here
  };

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>TestFolderPage</div>;
};

export default TestFolderPage;
```